# Attempting to align images on both sides of <p>

Tags: html, css

In my title I am trying to have two images on both sides of the text. I have tried a few methods, but none have worked. Here is my live [website](http://www.redstonegaming.com/). I would like to have the icons also automatically resize based on the window size. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Related code here:

```
<img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="left" src="favicon.ico">
<p align="middle" class="rusty"> RedstoneGaming </p>
<img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="right" src="favicon.ico">
```

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause(); // <-- another issue
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity linear 5.8s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.content
{
 opacity: .85;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
 z-index: 0; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position: relative;
 top:15%;
 left:15%;
 right:15%;
 width: 25vw;
 height:25vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
.border-right
{
 border-right: thick solid rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
.footer
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
 position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
 opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css" name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#"><!--Here is where-->
              <img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="left" src="favicon.ico"><p align="middle" class="rusty">   RedstoneGaming   </p><img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="right" src="favicon.ico">
            </a><!---------->
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
      <div class="border-right feed-column">
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;" class="rusty text-center">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column">
   </div>
    </div>
 <div class="footer">vv</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Trix Ok, I just did. I'm new here so thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `p` tag `inline`.

```
.rusty {
  font-family: "Rusty";
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
.menu li.current-item {
float:none;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer.[From view](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10634474)

Answer (score 1):

just change you code

```
<a href="#"><!--Here is where-->
  <img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="left" src="favicon.ico"><p align="middle" class="rusty">   RedstoneGaming   </p><img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="right" src="favicon.ico">
</a><!---------->"
```

to

```
<div> 
<div class="left">
    <img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="left" src="favicon.ico">
</div>
<div class="middle">
    <a href="#" align="middle" class="rusty">  RedstoneGaming </a>  </p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <img style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" align="right" src="favicon.ico">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

```
<style>
  .left{
    float:left;
  }
  .middle{
    float:left;
  }
  .right{
    float:left;
  }
  .clearfix{
    clear:both;
  }     
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of methods, each width some pros and cons.

If you need maximum possible browser compatibility, use:

### Method 1

**The markup:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="path/to/img"></td>
    <td><p>This is text</p></td>
    <td><img src="path/to/img"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**the CSS:**

```
table{ 
  width: 100%; border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center
}
table img, table p{
  display: inline
}
```

If you have some flexibility on browser compatiility, you may choose the inline-block method:

### Method 2

**The markup:**

```
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="path/to/img"><!--
    --><p>This is text</p><!--
    --><img src="path/to/img">
  </div>
```

**the CSS:**

```
.parent{ 
  text-align: center
}
img, p{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```